# Anko custom widget: editText without displaying error text

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext, anko

I trying make MyEditText extend EditText class with only one change:
not displaying "tooltip" with error. Only display icon (!) when editText.error = "some error"

```
class MyEditText : EditText {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun setError(error: CharSequence, icon: Drawable) {
        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null)
    }
}
```

When I use in Anko DSL

```
editText {
id = editNameId
}
```

and in code I tried cast:

```
private lateinit var editName: MyEditText

editName = find<MyEditText>(editNameId)
// or other variants
// editName = find<EditText>(editNameId)
// editName = find<EditText>(editNameId) as MyEditText
```

I got error that can't cast EditText to MyEditText. 
if I understand correctly, I need to make my own widget tag to Anko.

```
myEditText {
id = editNameId
}
```

I found that should work similar code to:

```
inline fun ViewManager.myEditText() = myEditText {}
inline fun ViewManager.myEditText(theme: Int = 0, init: MyEditText.() -> Unit) = ankoView({MyEditText(it)}, theme, init)
```

This is not working because I don't know how pass two parameters to the constructor: context and attrs.

I've been thinking about this problem for a long time and I can not solve it ;/

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to make your View class accessible from the DSL, and then create it explicitly.

Add this code to the file containing your custom view class:

```
inline fun ViewManager.myEditText(init: MyEditText.() -> Unit): MyEditText {
    return ankoView({ MyEditText(it) }, theme = 0, init = init)
}
```

Then you can use the following in your anko DSL:
    myEditText {id = editNameId}

Another recommended change is to not use view IDs, but rather just assign a variable from the DSL:

```
verticalLayout {
  editName = myEditText {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made final solution:

in extension.kt

```
class MyEditText : EditText {

var isError = true
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

override fun setError(error: CharSequence?, icon: Drawable?) {
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null)
    isError = error != null
} }

inline fun ViewManager.myEditText(theme: Int = 0, init: MyEditText.() -> Unit) = ankoView({MyEditText(it)}, theme, init)
```

In Anko DSL class (etName is defined in companion object)

```
myEditText {
   id = etName                
}
```

In activity

```
private lateinit var enterName: MyEditText
[..]
override fun onCreate [...]
{

enterName = find(etName)

 if (enterName.text.isNotEmpty()) enterName.error = null else enterName.error = "error"

 enterName.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
     override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
     if (s!!.isNotEmpty()) enterName.error = null else enterName.error = "error"
     validateForm()
     }

     override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
     override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
  })

validateForm()
// rest of onCreate
}

private fun validateForm() {
  editButton.isEnabled = enterName.isError == false
}
```